# Magento 1.9 - Is it save to delete all categories associated with products with 'parent_id' equals 0?

Tags: magento-1.9

In a custom module in Magento 1.9 I was associating products to categories using the following method:

```php
public function addProductToCategory($productId, $categoryId)
{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load($categoryId);

    $productsInCategory = $category->getProductsPosition();
    $productsInCategory[$productId] = 1;
    $category->setPostedProducts($productsInCategory);
    $category->save();
}
```

But, as you can see above, I forgot to check if the category actually exists before adding the product to it (using `if ($category->getId())` or similar).

This led me to some inconsistency at my database, where some categories were created with blank attributes and `parent_id` equals to `0` at the table `catalog_category_entity` (because the `$categoryId` was invalid).

My question is: can I revert it by selecting all categories associated to at least one product (joining the table `catalog_category_entity` with `catalog_category_product`) and deleting all categories with `parent_id` equals to `0`? Something like:

```php
$categoryProductTable = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getTableName("catalog/category_product");
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(array('p' => $categoryProductTable), 'p.category_id = e.entity_id')
    ->where("e.parent_id = 0")
    ->group("e.entity_id");
```

Where the SQL would be:

```sql
SELECT `e`.*, `p`.* FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `p` ON p.category_id = e.entity_id 
WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (e.parent_id = 0) 
GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id`;
```

I've tested the query above and it seems right, but I'm afraid to be missing something. Any other ideas to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> **Take the backup of your database before you run your DELETE query.**
>
> **After you run your SQL to remove the wrong records, reindex the store at first.**
>
> Then just use this code in your custom module method to assign the categories to products or in other
> words associate categories to a product, which keeps things much easier rather than the one that you use now.

```
 $_product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($productId);
 
 /* @var Magento_Catalog_Model_Product */
 $_product->setCategoryIds(array($categoryId))->save();
```

to get the list of categories a product has been assigned to

just use

```
$_product->getCategoryIds(); // returns the list of category Ids the product has been assigned to
```